# change the forecolor of the botton inside the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, colors, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">

   <ItemTemplate>              
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  CommandName="SaveId" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("subid") %>' OnClick="lnkSubject_CLick" Text='<%#Eval("subject") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

I need to change the forecolor of the botton inside the repeater that is clicked by the user.
When user click different button, all the buttons that had been clicked stay in blue.
I want only the current clicked button to be stay in blue.

```
protected void lnkSubject_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button Button2 = (Button)sender;

    Button2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    Button2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
protected void lnkSubject_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button Button2 = (Button)sender;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        Button otherButton = (Button)item.FindControl("Button2");
        if (otherButton.ForeColor != Color.Empty )
        {
            otherButton.ForeColor = Color.Empty;
            otherButton.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            otherButton.BorderColor = Color.Empty;
        }
     }
     Button2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
     Button2.BackColor = Color.White;
     Button2.BorderColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Here, I am only checking the `ForeColor` property, if you want you can check other properties too.